# Is there any way to disable file preallocation in Transmission on OSX?

Tags: macos, transmission

Is there any way to disable file preallocation in Transmission on OSX?

I've tried:

```
defaults write org.m0k.transmission PreAllocation 0
defaults write org.m0k.transmission Preallocation 0
defaults write org.m0k.transmission preallocation 0
```

But no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaults write org.m0k.transmission preallocation: 0
```

You forgot about ": "